# Receiving a NullPointerException while attempting to test local RabbitMQOutput

Tags: java, rabbitmq, azure-functions

I've setup a basic Azure function with the @TimerTrigger and @RabbitMQOutput annotations as mentioned here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-rabbitmq?tabs=in-process&pivots=programming-language-java

```
public class RabbitMQFunction {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RabbitMQFunction.class);
    /**
     * This function will be invoked periodically according to the specified schedule.
     */
    @FunctionName("RabbitMQFunction")
    public void run(
        @TimerTrigger(name = "timerInfo", schedule = "*/15 * * * * *") String timerInfo,
        @RabbitMQOutput(connectionStringSetting = "rabbitMQConnectionAppSetting", queueName = "myQueue", disableCertificateValidation = true) OutputBinding<String> output,
        final ExecutionContext context
    ) {
        logger.debug("START - RabbitMQFunction");
        context.getLogger().info("Java Timer trigger function executed at: " + LocalDateTime.now());
        output.setValue("Some string");
        logger.debug("END - RabbitMQFunction");
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I'm receiving the following error in the output when testing locally with Azurite in Visual Studio Code.  Here's the stack trace:

```
[2022-05-24T13:46:48.878Z] Received FunctionLoadResponse for function: 'RabbitMQFunction' with functionId: 'b09d265b-8b35-478f-8657-da7cf5b0fbc6'.
[2022-05-24T13:46:49.529Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000CEA4F55C'.
[2022-05-24T13:47:00.087Z] Executing 'Functions.RabbitMQFunction' (Reason='Timer fired at 2022-05-24T09:47:00.0322362-04:00', Id=a34b49d5-603f-4977-92f0-672f0d5feb86)
[2022-05-24T13:47:00.243Z] InvocationResponse received for invocation id: 'a34b49d5-603f-4977-92f0-672f0d5feb86'
[2022-05-24T13:47:00.325Z] Executed 'Functions.RabbitMQFunction' (Failed, Id=a34b49d5-603f-4977-92f0-672f0d5feb86, Duration=265ms)
[2022-05-24T13:47:00.327Z] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.RabbitMQFunction. System.Private.CoreLib: Result: Failure
Exception: NullPointerException:
Stack: java.lang.NullPointerException
[2022-05-24T13:47:00.329Z]      at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.binding.BindingDataStore.isDataTargetValid(BindingDataStore.java:145)       
[2022-05-24T13:47:00.331Z]      at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.binding.BindingDataStore.getOrAddDataTarget(BindingDataStore.java:123)      
[2022-05-24T13:47:00.333Z]      at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.broker.ParameterResolver.resolve(ParameterResolver.java:56)
[2022-05-24T13:47:00.334Z]      at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.broker.ParameterResolver.resolve(ParameterResolver.java:42)
[2022-05-24T13:47:00.336Z]      at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.broker.EnhancedJavaMethodExecutorImpl.execute(EnhancedJavaMethodExecutorImpl.java:53)
[2022-05-24T13:47:00.338Z]      at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.broker.JavaFunctionBroker.invokeMethod(JavaFunctionBroker.java:61)
[2022-05-24T13:47:00.339Z]      at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.handler.InvocationRequestHandler.execute(InvocationRequestHandler.java:33)  
[2022-05-24T13:47:00.341Z]      at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.handler.InvocationRequestHandler.execute(InvocationRequestHandler.java:10)  
[2022-05-24T13:47:00.342Z]      at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.handler.MessageHandler.handle(MessageHandler.java:45)
[2022-05-24T13:47:00.344Z]      at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.JavaWorkerClient$StreamingMessagePeer.lambda$onNext$0(JavaWorkerClient.java:92)
[2022-05-24T13:47:00.345Z]      at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
[2022-05-24T13:47:00.347Z]      at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
[2022-05-24T13:47:00.349Z]      at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
[2022-05-24T13:47:00.351Z]      at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
[2022-05-24T13:47:00.352Z]      at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
[2022-05-24T13:47:00.354Z] .
```

host.json contains:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[2.*, 3.0.0)"
  }
```

local.settings.json contains:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "java",
    "rabbitMQConnectionAppSetting": "amqp://guest:guest@127.0.0.1:5672/"
  }
}
```

build.gradle contains:

```
implementation 'com.microsoft.azure.functions:azure-functions-java-library:2.0.1'
implementation 'com.microsoft.azure.functions:azure-functions-java-library-rabbitmq:1.0.0'
// I've also tried with 2.0.0-preview
```

Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The exception comes from the [following line](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-java-worker/blob/dev/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/functions/worker/binding/BindingDataStore.java#L145) on github, which you can trace down to [this method](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-java-worker/blob/dev/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/functions/worker/broker/CoreTypeResolver.java#L47) where it tries to get the name of the annotated parameter. Have you tried updating the `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle` to a newer version?

Comment: Yes, I've also tried with the latest: [3.3.0, 4.0.0).
[edit] Same nullpointer error.  Also, I'm not able to add a name parameter to the annotation.

Comment: It should use the name attribute of [this annotation](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-rabbitmq-extension/blob/dev/java-library/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/functions/rabbitmq/annotation/RabbitMQOutput.java#L41), but that is where my debugging adventure halted. Maybe someone else has an idea. Otherwise i suggest you open a new issue at the [github page](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-java-worker/issues).

Answer (score 0):

The `getLogger()` function you have used is the reason for getting the null pointer exception.

This function will throw this exception if you don't provide a logger name.

So, this it should look like:

```
context.getLogger(RabbitMQFunction.class)
```

Refer this [following](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-logger#:%7E:text=Java%20Logging%20Levels%20%20%20%20S.%20No.,%20Configuration%20Information%20%205%20more%20rows%20) article from javapoint.

Comment: The logger on the Context accepts no arguments, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.functions.executioncontext.getlogger?view=azure-java-stable#com-microsoft-azure-functions-executioncontext-getlogger()

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  As @slindenau mentioned, it gives me a compile error if I try to pass an argument.  I did try removing all of the logging references and only kept:

output.setValue("Some string");

But, it still throws a NullPointerException.